# Why Hadoop name node connecting to weird [aca8ca1d.ipt.aol.com] hostname?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, hostname, namenode

I am using a mac system and starting a hadoop system, using the command:

```
start-dfs.sh
```

and my hostname is "ctpllt072.local" as returned by "hostname" command.
But i am getting a weird hostname and message when connecting starting the name node as follows:

```
Starting namenodes on [aca8ca1d.ipt.aol.com]
aca8ca1d.ipt.aol.com: ssh: connect to host aca8ca1d.ipt.aol.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I have nothing in my system as specified [aca8ca1d.ipt.aol.com], neither in /etc/hosts nor in any property file.

Here are my hdfs, yarn and core-site xml files:

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://172.168.***.***/</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hDir/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/karan.verma/Documents/backups/h/hDir/hdfs/namenode</value >
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>


        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
            <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Searched out for the reason on web, but no luck. Please suggest what could be the issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, i was actually trying to connect the aol server by mistake.
My IP starts with 192.168.***.*** and aloes ip is 172.168.**.** as stated on web (screenshot attached).
[image]

So changed my configuration to

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://192.168.***.***/</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```